# How to disable highlighted mode of NSStatusItem

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I'd like to set disable highlighted mode of `NSStatusItem` when clicked. In OS X 10.10 and later version, `highlightedMode` property has been deprecated, and Apple suggest using `button` property. So, what's the equivalent of `setHighlightedMode:`? Swift or Objective-C is OK.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the button's cell, cast as an `NSButtonCell*`, and set its `highlightsBy` property to 0. Of course, that involves cells, which are also being gradually deprecated.

Internally, `-[NSStatusItem setHighlightMode:]` calls `-[NSStatusBarButton setHighlightMode:]`, which calls `-[NSStatusBarButtonCell setHighlightMode:]`. That last calls `-setHighlightsBy:` on itself with either 0 or `NSContentsCellMask | NSChangeBackgroundCellMask`, depending on the mode. Unfortunately, neither `-[NSStatusBarButton setHighlightMode:]` nor `NSStatusBarButtonCell` are public API, so the best you can do is emulate them.

All told, it's probably best to just keep using `-[NSStatusItem setHighlightMode:]` and file a bug report with Apple requesting a non-deprecated approach.